# how to copy table ddl and data from another database in informix

Tags: java, informix

I have to copy table DDL and its data on informix database using java language.

here I have tried to use

```
create table xxx as select * from xxx;
```

The question of the solution are:
1 we should copy table from one database to another one, BUT here we only copy it in same database, I have tried use "database.table" to refer another one, that not work.
2 the whole DDL of old table cann't copy to new table, such as index definition.

there is any way to get the whole DDL of the old table using SQL so that I can execute that to another database to create same table in java language? Or other way to fix the problem?

Comment: Use the DB-Schema program (`dbschema`) to get a text file containing (a banner line and) the DDL statements needed to create the table and its constraints, etc.  Use the DB-Access program (`dbaccess`) to execute that file in the other database.

Comment: but in our scenario, we only can use pure sql or function running in java language to get DDL, is there any sql or function can do that?

Comment: You can run the queries that DB-Schema runs — but although the basics are easy enough, the full range of complexity for possible DDL statements is not pretty.  You can find out about the contortions that DB-Schema goes through by running (in a POSIX-like shell — Bourne, Korn, …) `SQLDEBUG=2:base dbschema -d dbase -t table` (to print the schema for a table called `table` in a database `dbase`), and then using `sqliprint base_*` to print the data generated.  You'll probably be surprised by the amount of SQL for even a simple table.